# How to use "respectively" correctly?

Tags: grammar

I have a question regarding how to correctly use "respectively." In the following sentence, do we need to use "respectively" at the end? My gut feeling is that we do NOT need to, but I am not so sure.

> When the temperature increased from 10 to 20 and to 30 degrees Celsius, the productivity increased from 45 to 56 and to 75.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But in your two examples, "I visited Paris and Rome respectively" and "Each one visited her own mother respectively," "respectively" is definitely not needed. In your first example, there is nothing for Paris and Rome to correspond to, so "respectively" does not relay any information.

Comment: I agree that in your new examples, "respectively" is indeed needed. Without the "respectively," which language is studied at which location is unclear. You do not have to study only French in Paris. Some time ago, I visited Bejing to learn English, not Chinese.

Comment: I don't know what this means: *increased from 10 to 20 and to 30*.  From 10 to 20 and from 10 to 30? Can you rephrase?

Comment: Tinfoil has a point. I'd use 'When the temperature increased from 10 to 20 and then to 30 degrees Celsius, the productivity increased from 45 to 56 and then to 75.'

Answer (score 1):

**Adding "respectively" adds clarity.**

Your intention presumably is to say that when the temperature increased to 10 degrees the productivity went to 45; when it went to 20 degrees the productivity went to 56; when it went to 30 degrees the productivity went to 75.

It is possible to read your sentence and not realize the pairing - to think that the productivity was 45 for one of the temperatures, 56 for one of the others, but without saying which. That is certainly an allowable meaning of the sentence. For a user to eliminate that interpretation they will have to understand something about the circumstances

If you think there is a danger of the sentence being misunderstood, add "respectively". But it's about how your readers will understand the situation, not about the grammar or meaning of the English language.

Answer (score -3):

To use respectively in sentences-
I respectively stood in the national anthem.
I respectively bowed my head as i got scolding from my mother.
Their sons Geogre and Jonathan,were three and six respectively.
We use respectively word like this.
Thanks i think it helped you .

Comment: There is a difference between *respectively* and *respectfully,* which I think you may have mixed up here.